# How to calculate dynamic price based on the volume of uploaded 3d file

Tags: php, wordpress, 3d, woocommerce

**Woocommerce Dynamic Price Based on the Volume of an Uploaded 3d File**

this is really driving me crazy.

I run a small foundry business on WP+Woocommerce,  and i'd need to **dynamically calculate the price** of my service, **based on the volume of 3d objects the users upload**.

I found on this website precious informations about how to calculate the volume of a 3d mesh, so i already wrote a php script to calculate it.

What is honestly completely obscure to me is which functions or hooks do I have to manipulate to tell woocommerce how to use it to calculate the final price (volume * basic price), like this:

1. *User uploads a 3d file and a script i already have calculates its volume and outputs its value in cubic units*;
2. *woocommerce takes the basic price I set (eg. 4€/cm3) and multiply that by said volume value output*;
3. *Woocommerce outputs the final price, and the user can add to cart*;

I'm trying with these:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','change_price', 10, 2); 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_regular_price','change_price', 10, 2); 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_sale_price','change_price', 10, 2);
```

and then a custom function with `$outputvolume * $price`, but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance to anybody who will help me even just understand where to start

Comment: As i said to Julian, what i really can't understand is where to tell woocommerce how to use it to calculate the final price (volume * basic price), then i'll try to program it by myself. Thank you

Comment: why is it not working? how are you doing it? seeing only filters in your question can't help us in knowing what the problem is.

Comment: You might get something here.. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111772/changing-woocommerce-display-price-based-on-user-role-category

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to derive volume from an uploaded 3d file with wordpress without custom php, unfortunately. This requires classes to even read such 3d files.
The easiest way would probably to hire a programmer to create a dedicated wordpress plugin - but that will cost you.

Having the user upload the file and derive the volume manually would probably remain the easiest and cost-saving solution.

Comment: Hello Julian thanks for your answer but maybe i wasn't clear about the fact i already have the php script to calculate the volume of an uploaded 3d file. What i really can't understand is where to tell woocommerce how to use it to calculate the final price (volume * basic price) (please refer to edited question). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It was all about knowing how to use woocommerce filters properly. 
I was doing basic mistakes...
Here, as suggested by Reigel, a good example of how to correctly use woocommerce price filters to manipulate prices with custom functions:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111772/changing-woocommerce-display-price-based-on-user-role-category